# Reverse array by group size

Tags: arrays, swift

I was trying to solve this challenge: reverse an array of elements by groups given a group size.

**Given Array**: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

**Desired Result** (group size of 3): [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]

If last group has less elements than the group size, then just add them and finish, as follows:

**Given Array**: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

**Desired Result**: [5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 1]

I tried this and it is working, but it looks kinda weird for me. Can anyone help me find a cleaner or much more intuitive solution?

```
extension Array {
    func reverse(groupSize: Int) -> [Element] {
        var reversed = [Element]()
        let groups = count / groupSize

        for group in 0...groups {
            let lowerBound = count - group * groupSize - groupSize
            let upperBound = count - 1 - group * groupSize

            if lowerBound >= 0 {
                reversed += Array(self[lowerBound...upperBound])
            } else {
                reversed += Array(self[0...upperBound])
            }
        }

        return reversed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say:

```
extension Array {

  func groupedReversing(stride: Int) -> [Element] {
    precondition(stride > 0, "stride must be > 0")

    return Swift.stride(from: count, to: 0, by: -stride)
            .flatMap { self[Swift.max(0, $0 - stride) ..< $0] }
  }
}

let result = Array(1 ... 7).groupedReversing(stride: 3)
print(result) // [5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

We're using `stride(from:through:by:)` to iterate from `array.count` (inclusive) to `0` (exclusive) in increments of (minus) the stride. The `Swift.` prefix is in order to disambiguate it from the obsoleted Swift 2 `stride` method (which [will be gone in Swift 4.1](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/11627)).

Then, we're flat-mapping the index to a slice of the input array that's up to `stride` elements long (truncating at the beginning of the array as we clamp the lower index to 0). And because this is [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap), the resulting slices are concatenated into a single resulting array.

You could also implement a fully generic version across `Sequence` by first providing an implementation on `BidirectionalCollection`, advancing indices backwards and appending slices into a resulting array:

```
extension BidirectionalCollection {

  func groupedReversing(stride: Int) -> [Element] {

    precondition(stride > 0, "stride must be > 0")

    var result: [Element] = []
    result.reserveCapacity(numericCast(count))

    var upper = endIndex
    while upper != startIndex {
      // get the next lower bound for the slice, stopping at the start index.
      let lower = index(upper, offsetBy: -numericCast(stride),
                        limitedBy: startIndex) ?? startIndex
      result += self[lower ..< upper]
      upper = lower
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

and then implement an overload on `Sequence` that first converts to an array, and then forwards onto the above implementation:

```
extension Sequence {
  func groupedReversing(stride: Int) -> [Element] {
    return Array(self).groupedReversing(stride: stride)
  }
}
```

Now you can call it on, for example, a `CountableClosedRange` without first having to convert it to an array:

```
let result = (1 ... 7).groupedReversing(stride: 3)
print(result) // [5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is based on a combo of `stride`+`map`:

```
let groupSize = 3
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let reversedArray = Array(array.reversed())
let result = stride(from: 0, to: reversedArray.count, by: groupSize).map {
  reversedArray[$0 ..< min($0 + groupSize, reversedArray.count)].reversed()
}.reduce([Int](), +)
print(result) //  [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You can add `result.reduce([Int](), +)` to make it become single array

Comment: clear and concise, will take into account with @Tj3n comment

Answer (score 1):

I think your function is okay, not sure what you meant by weird tbh, can separate to chunk or add each elements in reversed way ,but logic is same anyway, just need to mind the performance/complexity of each ways:

```
let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

extension Array {
    func reverse(group: Int) -> [Element] {
        guard group > 1 else { return self.reversed() }
        var new = [Element]()
        for i in stride(from: self.count-1, through: 0, by: -group) {
            let k = i-group+1 < 0 ? 0 : i-group+1
            for j in k...i {
                new.append(self[j])
            }
        }
        return new
    }
}

a.reverse(group: 4) //[8, 9, 10, 11, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You could also say `let k = Swift.max(0, i - group + 1)` instead of `let k = i-group+1 < 0 ? 0 : i-group+1`, and `new += self[k ... i]` instead of `for j in k...i { new.append(self[j]) }` :)

Answer (score 0):

The two following Swift 5 code snippets show how to implement a `Collection` or `Array` extension method in order to chunked it, reverse it then flatten it into a new array.

---

### #1. Using `AnyIterator` and `Sequence` `joined()`

```
extension Collection {

    func reverseFlattenChunked(by distance: Int) -> [Element] {
        precondition(distance > 0, "distance must be greater than 0")

        var index = endIndex
        let iterator = AnyIterator({ () -> SubSequence? in
            let newIndex = self.index(index, offsetBy: -distance, limitedBy: self.startIndex) ?? self.startIndex
            defer { index = newIndex }
            return index != self.startIndex ? self[newIndex ..< index] : nil
        })

        return Array(iterator.joined())
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
let newArray = array.reverseFlattenChunked(by: 3)
print(newArray) // prints: ["5", "6", "7", "2", "3", "4", "1"]
```

```
let array: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
let newArray = array.reverseFlattenChunked(by: 2)
print(newArray) // prints: ["5", "6", "3", "4", "1", "2"]
```

```
let array: [String] = []
let newArray = array.reverseFlattenChunked(by: 3)
print(newArray) // prints: []
```

---

### #2. Using `stride(from:to:by:)` and `Sequence` `flatMap(_:)`

```
extension Array {

    func reverseFlattenChunked(by distance: Int) -> [Element] {
        precondition(distance > 0, "distance must be greater than 0")

        let indicesSequence = stride(from: self.endIndex, to: self.startIndex, by: -distance)
        let array = indicesSequence.flatMap({ (index) -> SubSequence in
            let advancedIndex = self.index(index, offsetBy: -distance, limitedBy: self.startIndex) ?? self.startIndex
            // let advancedIndex = index.advanced(by: -distance) <= self.startIndex ? self.startIndex : index.advanced(by: -distance) // also works
            return self[advancedIndex ..< index]
        })

        return array
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
let newArray = array.reverseFlattenChunked(by: 3)
print(newArray) // prints: ["5", "6", "7", "2", "3", "4", "1"]
```

```
let array: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
let newArray = array.reverseFlattenChunked(by: 2)
print(newArray) // prints: ["5", "6", "3", "4", "1", "2"]
```

```
let array: [String] = []
let newArray = array.reverseFlattenChunked(by: 3)
print(newArray) // prints: []
```